# Unable to grab an element in a dynamic table where we have only text of a td tag

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, element

I have a table whose data changes according to what is added and deleted. In the table there are multiple columns Name, Qty, type, Status. All i have is the Name Text with me , i need to find the status field of that row which has that Name.

Problem is the html tags of  have same class names and i tried grabbing the parent and sibling everything failed. Please find the html structure of the table below:

```
    <table>
    <thead> </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr> 
       <td class = "c1"> 
         <a class = txtclass> text1  </a>
       </td>
       <td class = "c1"> Qty </td>
       <td class = "c2"> type </td>
       <td class = "c3"> 
         <div id = "1" class = "status1"> /div>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td class = "c1"> 
           <a> text2  </a>
        </td>
        <td class = "c1"> Qty </td>
        <td class = "c2"> type </td>
        <td class = "c3"> 
            <div id = "2" class = "status2"> /div>
        </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

So all i have with me is text2 and i need to get the  with the status of that row.

How do i proceed. I tried

```
  List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class =     'txtClass'][contains(text(),'text')]"));
        for(WebElement el1:ele)
        {
            WebElement parent = el1.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
            WebElement child1= parent.findElement(By.xpath("//td[4]/div"));
        System.out.println(child1.getAttribute("class"));
        }
```

this gives me the class name of the status of the first row in the table always.
Same i tried with

```
  WebElement child = el1.findElement(By.xpath("//following-sibling::td[4]/div[1]"));
```

i got the same thing class name of the first row in the table. I figured since the class name of the  are same for all child elements it will always grab the first row elements, and not the one from the row.

Please help i am stuck here for long, let me know if you need any other details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying using -

```
el1.findElements(By.xpath("//following-sibling::td[4]/div[1]"));
```

It is matching all the element present with format `td[4]/div[1]` in your page and retrieving first match.

You have to use following `xpath` to grab `status` present under `div` based on you text.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr/td[contains(.,'text1')]/following-sibling::td[3]/div")).getAttribute("class");
```

If your requirement to extract all status try following code-

```
 List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr/td[contains(.,'text2')]/following-sibling::td[3]/div"));
 for(WebElement element:allElements)
 {
    String status = element.getAttribute("class");
    System.out.println(status);
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Narendra this does not work. I am getting all the class names of the next sibling of all rows. not the one which has text1. i do not need all the status  of all rows. Only those rows which has the Name as text2.

Comment: @pragyadasgupta, I have updated the answer plz check . If your requirement to get all the status related to particular text.

Comment: Thanks a lot the second query worked for me when i put  td[3]  third sibling        `code`    List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr/td[contains(.,'text2')]/following-sibling::td[3]/div"));

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach suitable for you:

**Get all div elements containt attribute status :**

```
List<WebElement> listChildStatus = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr[.//a[contains(.,'text')]]//div"));
```

**Get specific div elements containt attribute status :**

```
WebElement childStatus = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[.//a[contains(.,'{TEXT}')]]//div"));
```

{TEXT} = the text value that you have

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate the element with the text, go one level up, and then get the sibling with the status

```
WebElement statusElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[a[contains(text(),'text2')]]/following-sibling::td[3]/div"));
String status = statusElement.getAttribute("class"); // will be status2
```

If you don't want to relay on index you can use `last()` to find the last sibling

```
WebElement statusElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[a[contains(text(),'text2')]]/following-sibling::td[last()]/div"));
```

Comment: Thank you , the last() will also work for me. It is always better to avoid the index.